# "I’ve made my mind up" or "I've made up my mind"

Tags: word-order

I'm a little confused about which is correct:

> I’ve made my mind **up**.

or

> I’ve made **up** my mind.

Comment: Avoid spliting group verbs.

Comment: [Bucks Fizz – **Making Your Mind Up** Lyrics](https://genius.com/Bucks-fizz-making-your-mind-up-lyrics). It's true that *grammarians* normally support @SovereignSun's position on this matter, but *in practice*, native speakers often ignore this principle in colloquial speech. If you check out *I have **made up** my mind* in Google Books you'll find the "incorrect" version *I have **made** my mind **up*** only occurs half as often, but that preference is reversed if we consider the more informal versions with ***I've*** instead of ***I have***. So approximately, both versions are "fine".